# Error 1009, MethodInfo-6()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, null, nullreferenceexception

Thanks to the stackoverflow community, I could fix some problems in my flash project yesterday. I still get an error message but it is coming from a different behavior in the website. This is the error message I get:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at MethodInfo-6()

This message appears again and again when I leave a page where snow flakes (particles) are falling. When I go back to this page the error message stops. My guess is that is is related to the snow flakes, when I try to remove the child from the parent.

I also get this error code mixed in with the other one but this one does not appear as often:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object
reference.at Snowflake/update()[C:\Users\JPL\Documents\ranchleblanc\New Ranch
Leblanc\website 2012\Snowflake.as:27]
```

Line 27 is this one in the following code: "parent.removeChild(this);"

I have been searching the internet for a way to fix this and I am stuck. Here is the snow flakes code. This movie clip is playing inside another movie clip.

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Snowflake extends MovieClip
{
    var yVel:Number;
    var xVel:Number;
    var stageheight:Number = 405;

    function Snowflake(xvel:Number, yvel:Number)
    {
        yVel = yvel;
        xVel = xvel;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    function update(e:Event):void
    {
        this.x += xVel;
        this.y += yVel;

        if (this.y > stageheight)
        {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the offending line (27) with

```
if(parent){
   parent.removeChild(this);
   this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}
```

make sure parent actually exists first.

you'll want to remove the event listener too, to prevent horrifying memory leakage.

In re MethodInfo-6()

So, I've seen that kind of message before but it's been a long time.  MethodInfo- functions are really internal functions in the Flash Player and should not be bugging you with their errors... If my memory serves me correctly, I encountered this in code someone else wrote in which they were trying to perform an action with a swf that had not yet loaded... or perhaps perform an action from inside the loaded swf that it was not yet actually able to perform at the time the code was called.

So here, let's see if we can sort out your problems a little bit.

Inside your acuiel_fla file, you have a number of things you're doing on frame 1 that assume that acuiel_fla *is the main timeline* which it will not be!  Try something like this...

```
// on frame 1...
// first, check if you even have a stage.  If not, wait to be added!
if(stage){
    init();
}else{
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}


// MOVE THE addEventListener call for ENTER_FRAME here!
function init(e:Event = null):void{
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, newFlake);
    this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStage);
}

// AND REMOVE the ENTER_FRAME listener if you are ever removed
// from the stage.
function removedFromStage(e:Event):void{
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, newFlake);
}

function randRange(low:Number, high:Number):Number
{
    var randNum:Number = Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
    return randNum;
}

//    DO NOT CALL IT HERE.
//this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, newFlake);

function newFlake(e:Event):void
{
    if(!stage) return; // we are not on stage so we can't
                       // do anything here!


    var flake:Snowflake = new Snowflake(randRange(-1,1), randRange(2,5));
    flake.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    flake.y = -5;
    flake.alpha = randRange(.3,1);
    flake.scaleX = flake.scaleY = randRange(.3,1);
    addChild(flake);
}

// do not instantiate your new flake here... just leave it for the enterframe.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed the second error message I was having. Line 27 does not throw an exception anymore. But I still get the message at MethodInfo-6().
Do you have any idea what this is?

Comment: @jpl You'll need to include the relevant code to be able to get any constructive help.. Your provided code doesn't have any issues other than what this answer and my answer cover.

Comment: @ Marty Wallace. The code for the two different pages that are related to this code are displayed in the question I asked yesterday. Sorry if it is long and painful to read. You can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205818/error-1009-actionscript-3)

Comment: @jpl No probs, I'll let you know if I notice anything!

Comment: @jpl Try this out.  Those MethodInfo errors are tricky to debug, and really the best way to solve them is to make sure your swf files never assume that they will be "immediately on stage."

Comment: Wow! This makes a lot of sense, and it works perfectly. Thank you very much. I will remember to call object that exists and to remove them properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(parent)
    parent.removeChild(this);
```